# Batteries with close capacity in series

Tags: power-supply, batteries, ampere-hour

I purchased an EPS systen of 2000VA, 36V.

Due to a crisis in my country I was able to find 3 batteries, one is a 180Ah deep cycle battery, the other two are 170Ah batteries. It's all I could find.

I intend to put them in series, I know its bad practice, but since they're very close in terms of Ah, would this cause me any issues?

EDIT: all three batteries are 12V batteries

Comment: Impossible to say for sure. Since they are different batteries, there might be other differences as well, not just the capacity.

Comment: All three are 12V batteries

Comment: Do all three have data sheets and, are they bought through recognized and trusted suppliers from recognized original manufacturers employing a decent quality system?

Answer (score 1):

Other than mentioning "deep cycle" you did not specify what type of battery they are.  There is a big difference in consequences if you put three uneven Lithium batteries when compared to three uneven Lead-Acid; since the term "deep-cycle" is usually reserved for Lead-Acid, let us assume so, although I will also talk about issues with Lithium batteries.

From a purely technical standpoint, the answer to "will this cause me any issues" is yes it will.  However, it is important to understand what these issues are.  If you are desperate and the benefit of having a functional system is high, then the issues may be acceptable.  Or depending on how you use them, these issues could be perfectly acceptable to you. As a quick preview, if the batteries are SLA, and you have any choice on setting the low-voltage cutoff, it will likely be just fine.

So here is what you have to keep in mind.  In a serial configuration, the same amount of current will flow through all batteries during charge and discharge.  As the batteries are of different capacities, they are likely to get out-of-sync, meaning some will end up emptier than others during discharge and vice versa.  Keep in mind that 180 A-hr and 170 A-hr batteries aren't that different, about 6% variation would not unheard of even among the same battery type.  I would worry more about the difference between battery vendors but the point is, the batteries are close, which makes it easier to use as you propose.

Below are some things to consider.

### Considerations during use (discharge)

Because they are different capacities, the lowest capacity battery will discharge faster than the others.  What will happen if you use the "combined" battery till the voltage drops to a value 3 x the 12V battery low threshold, then almost certainly the weaker battery will go below that threshold.  Depending on the battery chemistry, this can cause damage (Lithium), or simply reduce the life of the battery (Lead Acid).
However, if you monitor each battery individually and only use them till any of the batteries have reached the lowest voltage threshold, it will be fine.  You may not get the full capacity of the string, but it will work just fine.

You can experiment by starting with all batteries full and monitoring individual battery voltages during use.  You will then see what the total voltage is when the weakest (or any for that matter) battery reaches the discharged point.  You can then set the total voltage (plus a bit of cushion, maybe 0.3V) as the cutoff in the inverter, and that that will prevent any battery from going below the acceptable discharge level.

### Considerations during charging

A lot depends here on the type of battery you are using.  Your typical Lithium 12V battery already contains a protection circuit that will prevent overcharging the battery.  So if you try to charge them as a unit, the first battery to fully charge will cut-off and the rest of the batteries will be undercharged.  All in all, the consequences, in this case, are loss of capacity. I won't even go into the case of charging three 12V Lithium batteries without internal protection circuits (I'm not even sure you can buy these).
If the batteries are SLA, things are significantly simpler.  Lead-acid batteries can allow a small amount of current through them once fully charged without any consequence - the trickle charge.  What can happen during charging is that if the lower capacity battery reaches full charge first, it should tolerate extra current while the higher capacity batteries top off.  If the imbalance is extreme, the high amount of current could damage the weaker battery.  At the same time, if the lowest capacity battery is the most discharged at the beginning of the charge cycle, it could be that the higher capacity batteries are "strained" as the low voltage of the weak battery will trick the charger into putting full current even though the high capacity batteries are full.  Despite the SLA tolerance for slight overcharge, this could cause damage issues.  But again, given the 6% difference in capacity, this is unlikely.

As before, you could monitor the batteries during charge and set the max voltage on the inverter to a value below that, ensuring no battery is stressed, but also realize you are losing capacity.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with large, lead-acid wet cells that are set up for deep cycling.

Honestly, of all the things that threaten lead-acid batteries, the minor mismatch is the least of your concerns.

Lead-acid batteries are hurt by deep discharging. So if you use even 50% of their capacity regularly, you will shorten their life.  Good system design accounts for this, and aims to usually draw them down no more than 30%-ish.

As such, if your system is so designed, you simply won't be stressing the batteries enough for these differences to matter.  If the system is not well designed, you'd soon destroy evenly a perfectly matched set.

Realize to get 2000 VA, you must pull 60A from the battery.  At full draw, that will use up 30% of capacity in less than an hour. So I gather you are not doing that.

As far as balancing, lead-acid batteries have a neat trick.  The closer they are to full, the less efficiently they charge. This helps the lowest cell catch up, since it is charging more efficiently than its peers.  So they tend to passively self-balance, assuming they are not too far askew.   Don't let them get askew.

Answer (score 0):

It is really likely it will cause you issues. Some of them:

1. If one battery can output 1Ah and another 0.5Ah, and your EPS draws 1Ah, it will get the 0.5Ah battery hot. Result: overheat, explosion.
2. When charging the batteries, they will get charged uneven. The smallest capacity batteries will get charged first (say they reach 13V and 13V each), your last battery will get charged only to 10V). Result: lower battery life.